# That box will never get opened vs will never be opened

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, phrases, grammaticality-in-context, informal-language

What is the difference and which is more correct?

That box will never get opened vs  will never be opened.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, the first uses the "get passive".

The get-passive is more dynamic than the be-passive, and it can't be used with stative verbs. It is often used conversationally to bring attention to specific actions (rather than states), and so can be used particularly with events that are seen as specifically desirable or specifically undesirable.

See [the get passive|](https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/the-passive-voice-with-get-/4839624.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20passive%20sentence%2C%20the,My%20favorite%20cup%20got%20broken.%E2%80%9D)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.

We use **be + past participle** in passive voice.

We can also use **get + past participle** to form passive voice.

Answer (score -1):

The standard English usage is:

*That box will never be opened.*

The source of the confusion is that in *get opened* the word *get* is being

> *used with the past participle of [a] transitive verb as a passive voice auxiliary...*
>
> ```
> and
> ```
>
> *get...remains...unpredictable...when...a passive auxiliary.*

All cited information is from the [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get) website.

Comment: only "unpredictable" in pronunciation.  Some Americans say "git", but it isn't particularly tied to a dialect, and hence is "unpredictable".

Comment: In my opinion, the use of "get" as an auxiliary verb is unpredictable in itself. I understand that my quote came from an ostensible pronunciation guide, but my generalization of its point is accurate (plus, I disagree that one speaker will have varying pronunciations of the word that correlate with its varying functional usages; that idea is a stretch),

Comment: The trouble I have is that you've taken that usage note about pronunciation and edited to suggest that Merriam-Webster dictionary claim that the "get passive" is  not a regular part of English.  The dictionary doesn't say that, so the edited quote is misleading.  If *you* claim that the get passive is "unpredictable" (from your native judgement) you should make that clear.

Comment: I _do_ claim that the passive-voice auxiliary usage is unpredictable and I hope I have made this clear.

Comment: No, you have not. You have suggested authority for your claim that does not exist.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the material on the MW site. The paragraph starts by describing a pronunciation of the word _get_ as a "feature" of some English dialects and then the text transitions into a description of the word's lexical usage. A "feature" of some distinct pronunciation variant of the word is not what "remains in widespread and unpredictable use" but instead it is the word itself which does so.